# Angular push into a list for subject has only one node instead of all items

Tags: javascript, angular, list, typescript, subject

I am trying to implement functionality which has a tree/hierarchy structure on the left and it displays a list of the selected values on the right.

I have the selected node value in "currentNode". I am trying to push it in a list called "selections". This list should have all of the selected nodes (when selected on the left, it gets pushed in the list).

I am then passing this list through a "rightSideSubject". The component which has been created for the right side code, will take this subject as an input and display.

I am stuck in the first step itself because when I am trying to display my list "selections", it has only the currently selected node and not all of the nodes which have been selected.

checkbox-tree.component.ts:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeNode } from './../../dto/TreeNode';
import { BaseTreeComponent } from './../base-tree/base-tree.component';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import html from './checkbox-tree.component.html';
import css from '../fortune-select.component.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-tree',
  template: html,
  styles: [css],
})

export class CheckboxTreeComponent<T> extends BaseTreeComponent<T> {
  rightSideSubject                  = new Subject<TreeNode<T>[]>();
  selections: TreeNode<T>[] = [];



  //gets called when a node is selected
  public selected():void {
    if(!this.linked || (this.currentNode.indeterminate && !this.currentNode.selected)) {
      this.dataChangedEvent();
      return;
    }

    this.currentNode.indeterminate = false;
    if(this.singleLevelOnly) {
      this.currentNode.selectChildrenSingleLevel(this.currentNode.selected);
    } else {
      this.currentNode.selectChildren(this.currentNode.selected);
    }

    this.selections.push(this.currentNode);
    this.rightSideSubject.next(this.selections);
    console.log(this.selections);
    this.childChanged.emit();
    this.dataChangedEvent();
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the list of selected nodes (by maintaining the order of selection)?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: in LeftSide Component, console.log(this.selections); prints the value?